# Extending PC desktop to iPad over Bluetooth?

Tags: multiple-monitors, bluetooth, ipad, tablet

I want to extend my Windows 7 laptop's screen to my iPad.  I know I can do this through something like Air Display if both the laptop and the iPad are on the same wireless network.

Can I do the same thing if they are not on a network?  If I'm in a bunker with no WiFi, does anyone know of a utility that would let me do this over Bluetooth, for example? (I know - I don't know how this would happen, I just want to be sure I'm not missing anything obvious.)

Comment: You could create an ad-hoc wireless network, that connects your laptop directly to your iPad without a dedicated wifi router around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad does not support the use of Bluetooth for networking, unless of of course you jailbreak it. The best solution for your problem, like Weltenwanderer said, is to create an ad-hoc wireless network between your devices.